# Take last n element in Kotlin

Tags: functional-programming, kotlin

I have a list on which I'd like to apply some transformations, but excluding the first 2 elements. How can I do it the nicest way? Something like this:

```
list.reversed().take(list.size - 2)...(my transformations)
```

or

```
list.excludeFirstN(2)...(my transformations)
```

Comment: please clarify the question (and the answer): did you want to apply a transformation to all elements except for two of them, or did you want to drop these two forever?

Comment: Please post the code that solved your problem (you may update the question). There is a good chance someone can suggest a shorter or more idiomatic way to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Oh, I found the [drop()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/drop.html) function.

Comment: FYI: There is also [`takeLast`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/take-last.html) if you actually want to "take last n element in Kotlin".

Comment: takeLast is not showing up for me in the IDE. I called asSequence() on a Java Iterator.

Answer (score 25):

You can use [takeLast(n)](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/take-last.html) like:

```
list.takeLast(3)
```

But be carful, the last number is represented first, so you may need to use [reversed](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reversed.html) as well, so your code could be:

```
list.takeLast(3).reversed()
```

Comment: seems like takeLast keeps original order now 
https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/7a7d392b3470b38d42f80c896b7270678d0f95c3/libraries/stdlib/common/src/generated/_Arrays.kt#L4984

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned, `drop` is a good fit for the use case:

```
listOf(1,2,3,4).drop(2).forEach(::println)
```

Otherwise, you can also filter by index:

```
listOf(1,2,3,4).filterIndexed { index, _ -> index > 1 }.forEach(::println)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this :

**1**. via kotlin collections (**takeLast**) :

```
 val numbers = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
 val lastThree = numbers.takeLast(3)//  3,4,5 no need to reverse
```

**2**. via kotlin collections (**subList**) :

```
val numbers = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val lastThree = numbers.subList(numbers.size - 3, numbers.size) // 3,4,5
// flexible
```

**3**. via kotlin collections (**drop**) :

```
 val numbers = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
 val lastThree = numbers.drop(numbers.size-3) // 3,4,5
```

**4**. via stream (**skip**) :

```
fun getLastNItems(list: List<Int>, n: Int): List<Int> {
    return list.stream()
        .skip(list.size - n)
        .limit(n) // truncated to be no longer than n
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
}
```

**5**. via stream (**takeWhile/reverse**) :

```
fun getLastNItems(list: List<Int>, n: Int): List<Int> {
    return list.stream()
        .takeWhile { it -> list.indexOf(it) < n }
        .reverse()
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
}
```

**6**. By **manually** making a sub list :

```
fun getLastNItems(list: List<Any>, n: Int): List<Any> {
    if (n > list.size) 
        throw IllegalArgumentException("n cannot be greater than the size of the list")

    val subList = mutableListOf<Any>()
    for (i in list.size - n until list.size)
        subList.add(list[i])

    return subList
}
```